# proof that STRIPS terminates

Tags: artificial-intelligence, planning

I was reading page 6 of https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~reids/planning/handouts/Linear.pdf

And it is not clear to me that the STRIPS algorithm necessarily terminates.

Namely if we have a simple goal sg on the stack, and CANNOT find an operator O whose addlist includes all of sg, how do we go about picking operators? At this point it seems very easy to create counterexamples that cause the algorithm to loop, regardless of what heuristic one selects.

Furthermore, if we have multiple operators each of whose addlist includes all of sg, how do we pick the best operator (or is the choice arbitrary?).